# String Array for with n elements

Tags: matlab

I want to make a array of strings, like this one, numel(A) = 4:

> > A = ['a' 'a' 'a' 'a']

A = aaaa

For I could make easy changes in like this:

> > A(2) = 't'

A = ataa

But, I want to make something like this for an array size n.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing it for an array of size `n`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It seems that you need to use [repmat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much of a question here.  But if you are just asking how to make a 1xN array of the char 'a'.  Then it is just this:

```
N = 10;
A(1:N) = 'a'
```

Comment: Yes, sorry for the wrongs in the questions. I didn't found any form to make it and didn't know this structure of building.